# SQL Statement outputs duplicate results? [FIXED, IGNORE THE QUESTION]

Tags: mysql, duplicates, output

So, I am running some practice statements for a database I am learning with, and on the instructions, it says I should be able to write a statement that returns 9 rows of data. This is the instructions:

- Write a SELECT statement that returns these columns from the Orders table:  (9 rows)
- The card_number column
- The length of the card_number column
- The last four digits of the card_number column
- When you get that working right, add the columns that follow to the result set. This is more difficult because these columns require the use of functions within functions. A column that displays the last four digits of the card_number column in this format: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1234. In other words, use Xs for the first 12 digits of the card number and actual numbers for the last four digits of the number.

This is the statement that I wrote:

```
SELECT 
    o.card_number,
    LENGTH(o.card_number) AS card__number_length,
    RIGHT(o.card_number, 4) AS last_four_digits,
    INSERT(RIGHT(o.card_number, 4), 1, 0,
        'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-') AS xx_format
FROM
    orders o
        INNER JOIN
    order_items oi ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
        INNER JOIN
    products p ON p.product_id = oi.product_id
ORDER BY o.card_number;
```

The statement outputs 12 rows instead of 9, where the `'4111111111111111', '16', '1111', 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1111'`
row duplicates at least 5 times. I don't know how exactly this is happening and was wondering if anyone knew how to fix it?

My database:
https://pastebin.com/ajKS81hw

Comment: Why do you join the other tables to orders?

Comment: You have multiple `order_item` for each `order` AND you join in `order_items` table and therefore you get all of its records. Just because you don't display any columns from your `order_items` table doesn't mean the join didn't happen. In the future don't include tables you don't need/use in your `FROM` clause.

Comment: @JNevill Oh, I understand now. I deleted everything after `FROM orders o;` and it seemed to fix the problem. Thank you for pointing that out. I don't think I would have ever realized what a big mistake that was.